# using BOXY JQuery plugin

Tags: css, ruby, jquery

I am using the following boxy plugin for some of my pages. [BOXY PLUGIN](http://onehackoranother.com/projects/jquery/boxy/)

I would like to have a different style of the outer box of the boxy popup for EACH page. The issue is that I had noticed hardcoded html and css classes in the boxy.js file. Can someone please help me out and point me to the right direction? I would like to use different styling per page using the same boxy plugin.

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily overwrite CSS properties if:

- It has a more specific selector (eg. `img.myClass` beats `.myClass`)
- It is defined later in the code
- You use `!important` in a property

Though the `!important` feature is often misused, causing many developers to not like it, but it's in fact very useful when used correctly. When you want to overwrite 3rd party CSS for example ;)

```
.myClass {
    color: red;
}

.myClass {
    color: blue !important; /* overwrites the red color */
}
```